# Return a rowset and set a variable in an "IN" clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want use the SQL Server `IN` operator and also set a variable to a column value. Is this possible?

My code is like this:

```
DECLARE @SubkindId as tinyint;

SELECT NAME FROM SampleTable001 WHERE 
Id in (SELECT Id, @SubkindId = Subkind FROM SampleTable002)
ORDER BY Name;
```

My issue is: I want to set the @SubkindId variable in the inner select statement.

Comment: Inline assignment in MySQL is possible. It's possible on Sql Server too, but on limited way only, i.e. on independent query only

Comment: @MichaelBuen close... you can do variable assignment in an independent SELECT, true, but you can also do it in an UPDATE statement as well. Thanks for the info about MySQL.

Comment: @ErikE Thanks for the info too, yep variable assignment on the UPDATE query is available on SQL Server as well, example: http://www.ienablemuch.com/2012/05/recursive-cte-is-evil-and-cursor-is.html  Here's MySQL's variable assignment on steroids example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f157b/1 There are far more legitimate use for variable-assignments-anywhere than the contrived MySQL example I give ツ

Comment: @Michael sqlfiddle on mobile has challenges!

Comment: @ErikE - hey I'm the owner of sqlfiddle, could you let me know what trouble you're having on a mobile device?  Maybe email admin at sqlfiddle dot com and let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

### Can It Be Done?

In SQL Server you can't SELECT a result set *and* SET variables in the same statement (though you can in MySQL). Sorry. But there may be another way to get what you want. Unfortunately, what you want is not completely clear.

Assuming you want to do a SELECT and at the same time return another value into a variable, you have to handle the issue that your query can return multiple rows, so in that case, which one would you want to return into `@SubkindId`?

Now, I may have misunderstood, and instead of trying to pull the column value *into* the variable, you instead want to pull only the row where the `SubkindId` *matches* the value already in the variable (though you didn't show assigning a value to it first, so this seems less likely).

**Please confirm which is the case and answer the above questions, and I can help you more.**

In the meantime, I'll try to give you answers for both scenarios.

First, let me mention that I recommend against using the `IN()` syntax with a subquery returning a list of IDs. It is poor practice in my opinion because it usually demonstrates that the person doesn't really know how to JOIN properly, and as soon as the query gets a little complicated, not only that person but even the best professional SQL Server query writer can get lost `(... WHERE x IN (SELECT ... WHERE y IN (SELECT ... WHERE z NOT IN (...)))` which soon leads to a serious case of *what!?!?!?!*. Just use JOINs, and if required, semi-joins (introduced with an EXISTS clause).

### Query and Return a Value

If what you really wanted was to get access to the values that the SELECT statement found while doing its join, it might look something like this:

```
DECLARE @KindsAndSubkinds TABLE (
   Name varchar(100),
   SubkindId tinyint
);

INSERT @KindsAndSubkinds
SELECT
   T1.Name,
   T2.SubkindId
FROM
   dbo.SampleTable001 T1
   INNER JOIN dbo.SampleTable002 T2
      ON T1.Id = T2.Id

SELECT DISTINCT Name
FROM @KindsAndSubkinds
ORDER BY Name;

-- Now you can something with the `SubkindId`s in the @KindsAndSubkinds table variable.
```

### Just Query

If you really were just trying to query rather than return a value, this is what I would recommend:

```
DECLARE @SubkindId as tinyint;
SET @SubkindId = 5;

SELECT
   T1.Name
FROM
   dbo.SampleTable001 T1
   INNER JOIN dbo.SampleTable002 T2
      ON T1.Id = T2.Id
WHERE
   T2.Subkind = @SubkindId
ORDER BY
   T1.Name;
```

If there are multiple rows in SampleTable002 but you don't want them in the result set, then:

```
SELECT
   T1.Name
FROM
   dbo.SampleTable001 T1
WHERE
   EXISTS ( 
   -- This semi-join requires at least one row to exist
   -- but doesn't increase the row count
      SELECT *
      FROM dbo.SampleTable002 T2
      WHERE
         T1.Id = T2.Id
         AND T2.Subkind = @SubkindId
   )
ORDER BY
   T1.Name;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I just want set the @SubkindId in secound select statement.that it is possible in this code [select @SubkindId=Subkind from SampleTable002]

Comment: @RezaNabati I already explained that you can't do that. Please answer the questions I posed to you. Specifically, your query doesn't seem very selective--it looks like it could return a lot of rows because you're just joining on a generic ID. Which row value do you want to appear in the variable? The variable is a scalar and can only have one value. So if there are 10 rows in the SELECT query, which one goes in the variable? The first? The last? The 5th? What?

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
DECLARE @SubkindId as tinyint

SELECT [NAME] 
FROM SampleTable001 
WHERE  Id in (SELECT Id 
              from SampleTable002
              WHERE Subkind=@SubkindId)
order by [Name]
```

or by using `JOIN`

```
DECLARE @SubkindId as tinyint

SELECT [NAME] 
FROM SampleTable001 a 
        INNER JOIN  SampleTable002 b
          ON a.id = b.id
WHERE b.Subkind=@SubkindId
order by [Name]
```